# How to interactively communicate with a python3 programme from a node one?

Tags: python, node.js, pipe, python-3.5

I have the following "bot" python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import sys


def callback(*args):
    data = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
    print('ECHO: {}'.format(data), flush=True)
    if data == 'EOF':
        loop.stop()

print('Bot spawning!')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.add_reader(sys.stdin.fileno(), callback)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
print('Bot dead')
```

that should be handled by this node application:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
const createInterface = require('readline').createInterface
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

const lines = [
  'I',
  'LOVE',
  'DEAD',
  'BEEF',
  'EOF',
]
const bot = spawn('./poc.py')
const rl = createInterface({
  input: bot.stdout,
})
rl.on('line', line => {
  console.log('BOT SAYS', new Array(line))
})
// bot.stdout.on('data', data => {
//     console.log(`BOT SAYS: ${data}`)
// })

bot.stdin.on('error', (err) => console.log(err))

try {
  console.log('Dispatching lines...')
  lines.forEach( line => {
    console.log('Connected', bot.connected)
    console.log('Sending', line)
    bot.stdin.write(`${line}\n`)
  })
}
finally {
  // bot.stdin.end()
}
```

The problem is that unless I uncomment the line `bot.stdin.end()` I won't get any output from the bot (in a couple of runs I got two lines back, but not all of them).

I tried different approaches like reading directly from `bot.stdout`, or explicitly flushing the buffers in the python programme, or using `execFile` rather than spawn... but all to no avail.

So my question is: **how can I have the node programme interactively communicate via `stdin` and `stdout` with another process, without having to close a pipe, or wait for the execution of said process to finish?**

Maybe there is a totally different approach I should follow?

**EDIT**: Running the above code on my Fedora 25 station cause the following output and the programme to hang up indefinitively:

```
[] % ./poc.js  
Dispatching lines...
Connected false
Sending I
Connected false
Sending LOVE
Connected false
Sending DEAD
Connected false
Sending BEEF
Connected false
Sending EOF
BOT SAYS [ 'Bot spawning!' ]
BOT SAYS [ 'ECHO: I' ]
```

Note that the child process `bot` is disconnected all the time, and yet two lines of the input get processed nevertheless...

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem not with how your bot writes its output, but with how it processes its input.

asyncio notices there's data in the input stream, and calls the callback, but the callback doesn't get around to processing all the available input. The callback isn't called again, because the stream didn't change since, and the remaining input is likely kept in a buffer, waiting.

I think you would want your callback to process any input until it can fetch no more, before returning.

Comment: I will try that when I have a minute (possibly tonight at home).  Thanks for the suggestion for now! :)